# How to get rid of this excess scroll down bar

Tags: html, css, user-interface, webix

[image: Two Scroll Bars]

I'm just developing a Reproting Tool and due to some reason i have two scroll bars,one which is for Chrome or any other browser and the other is part of the HTML,i couldn't trace anything back to the HTML..
[image: HTML Code]

```
> </head>
<body style="min-height:20px">
    <!-- START PAGE CONTAINER -->
    <div class="page-container" style="min-height:20px">

        <!-- START PAGE SIDEBAR -->
        <div class="page-sidebar">
            <!-- START X-NAVIGATION -->
            <ul class="x-navigation">
                <li class="xn-logo">
                    <a href="index.html">Reports</a>
                    <a href="#" class="x-navigation-control"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="xn-profile">
                    <!--<a href="#" class="profile-mini">
                        <img src="assets/images/users/avatar.jpg" alt="John Doe" />
                    </a>-->
                    <div class="profile">
                        <!--<div class="profile-image">
                            <img src="assets/images/users/avatar.jpg" alt="John Doe" />
                        </div>-->
                        <!--<div class="profile-data">
                            <div class="profile-data-name">John Doe</div>
                            <div class="profile-data-title">Web Developer/Designer</div>
                        </div>-->
                        <!--<div class="profile-controls">
                            <a href="pages-profile.html" class="profile-control-left"><span class="fa fa-info"></span></a>
                            <a href="pages-messages.html" class="profile-control-right"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></a>
                        </div>-->
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="xn-title">Navigation</li>
                <li >
                    <a href="/reports"><span class="fa fa-cogs fa-spin" title="Configure Reports"></span> <span class="xn-text">Configure Reports</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/dashboard"><span class="fa fa-cogs fa-spin" title="Configure Dashboard"></span> <span class="xn-text">Configure Dashboard</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-eye" title="View Dashboard"></span> <span class="xn-text">View Dashboard</span></a>
                </li>


            </ul>
            <!-- END X-NAVIGATION -->
```

Any Help would be deeply appreciated

Comment: Show the code. BTW you can try ```overflow-y: hidden;```

Comment: Added the code in the 2nd screenshot,shall i add more ?? and what do you mean by overflow-y: hidden;

Comment: The screenshot code is not helpful If you really want that someone can solve your issue. Btw set the ```overflow-y: hidden;``` styling to your element which you don't want to scroll.

Comment: thank you let me check @aavrug

Comment: @aavrug html added,could you check ??

Comment: try to execute the code you provided and tell me if you see the issue. If not then please provide the CSS too :)

Comment: @aavrug..added this in main.css as .page-sidebar,bu hasn't made any difference

Comment: Show the working example that's what we are looking for.

Comment: so added overflow to .page-container and it seems to have taken the scroll off of the page.. :) thanks a lot for your inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is

to the main div you can apply css like for example you have

```
<div class ="main">
   // rest of your code 
</div>
```

in your main style.css  you can put

```
.main {
    width:100%;
    height:90%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

if this doesn't work you can use

```
body {
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

Comment: there's no main in my code :(,but ive added the code

Comment: use this and let me know if it works                                                                   .page-sidebar  {  overflow-y:hidden; }

Comment: so added overflow to .page-container and it seems to have taken the scroll off of the page.. :) thanks a lot for your inputs

Comment: happy to help you :-) @Venky an up vote will be appreciable ;-)